# Regarding regular expression in Perl

Tags: perl

I want to grep date and time written in below format and assign it to a variable removing the spaces and colons.  Please suggest regular expressions for this.

```
07 Aug 2015 00:09:14
```

The thing is that I want to grep this format in a specific line which contains "CURRENT_RUN_ID". For example: the line would be like this:

```
07 Aug 2015 00:09:14 -- INFO -- *** CURRENT_RUN_ID=600
```

I need to grab the date and time only from this specific line which contains "CURRENT_RUN_ID".

Comment: What have you tried?  How would you check that the line contains the current run ID string?  How would you then extract the date/time portion from a line?  It all looks pretty straight-forward if you do it in two operations.  If you think you must do it all in one, then it can be done too, but doing the operations separately is probably simpler — and simple is probably better if you're having to ask how to do it.

Answer (score 4):

I wouldn't use a regex for this.  Instead, I would split the message on the `--` delimiter.  This simplifies the problem by separating parsing the whole line from parsing the date.

```
# 07 Aug 2015 00:09:14 -- INFO -- *** CURRENT_RUN_ID=600
my($date_string, $flag, $message) = split /\s*--\s*/, $line, 3;
```

Then I'd turn the date into a Time::Piece object using [Time::Piece->strptime](https://metacpan.org/pod/Time::Piece#Date-Parsing).  This takes format arguments like [strftime](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strftime).

```
my $date = Time::Piece->strptime($date_string, '%d %b %Y %H:%M:%S');
```

Then you can play with `$date` as a handy Time::Piece object.

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

while (<>)
{
    if (m/^(\d\d) (\w{3}) (\d{4}) (\d\d):(\d\d):(\d\d) .*CURRENT_RUN_ID/)
    {
        my $var = "$1$2$3$4$5$6";
        print "$var\n";
    }
}
```

Look for 2 digits, 3 letters, 4 digits, and a sequence of pairs of digits with blanks and colons as separators, followed by `CURRENT_RUN_ID`.  If it matches, assemble the string without spaces or colons, and assign to a variable.  Print.

Answer (score 1):

First regex here to get the matching line. Second regex removes space & ':' from date time.

```
my $string = '07 Aug 2015 00:09:14 -- INFO -- *** CURRENT_RUN_ID=600';
if ($string =~ /^(\d{2}\s[A-Z][a-z]{2}\s\d{4}\s\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}).+CURRENT_RUN_ID/) {
    my $datetime = $1;
    $datetime =~ s/[\s|:]//gc;
}
```